# Rails. Routing problem with 2 User models for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models, Accountant and Customer. I want to do the auth with Devise. I have following config:

In routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # devise_for :accountants, path: 'accountants'
  devise_for :accountants, path: 'accountants', controllers: { registrations: 'accountants/registrations', sessions: 'accountants/sessions' }

  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get "registration", to: "pages#registration"
end
```

Accountant.rb

```
class Accountant < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company
end
```

accountants/new.html.erb

### Sign up for accountants

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: accountant_registration_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: true,
                autofocus: true ,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
    <%= f.input :password,
                required: true,
                hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length),
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation,
                required: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "accountants/shared/links" %>
```

I used:

```
rails generate devise:controllers accountants
```

to create following controller

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Accountants::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end
```

After hitting sign up, I am redirected to the /accountants url, where I see the sign up form, with the validation error. 6 characters minimum (and the email is displayed), (I put a 6-character password).

Any help on how to debug this?

The routes are as follow:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        new_accountant_session GET    /accountants/sign_in(.:format)                                                           accountants/sessions#new
            accountant_session POST   /accountants/sign_in(.:format)                                                           accountants/sessions#create
    destroy_accountant_session DELETE /accountants/sign_out(.:format)                                                          accountants/sessions#destroy
       new_accountant_password GET    /accountants/password/new(.:format)                                                      devise/passwords#new
      edit_accountant_password GET    /accountants/password/edit(.:format)                                                     devise/passwords#edit
           accountant_password PATCH  /accountants/password(.:format)                                                          devise/passwords#update
                               PUT    /accountants/password(.:format)                                                          devise/passwords#update
                               POST   /accountants/password(.:format)                                                          devise/passwords#create
cancel_accountant_registration GET    /accountants/cancel(.:format)                                                            accountants/registrations#cancel
   new_accountant_registration GET    /accountants/sign_up(.:format)                                                           accountants/registrations#new
  edit_accountant_registration GET    /accountants/edit(.:format)                                                              accountants/registrations#edit
       accountant_registration PATCH  /accountants(.:format)                                                                   accountants/registrations#update
                               PUT    /accountants(.:format)                                                                   accountants/registrations#update
                               DELETE /accountants(.:format)                                                                   accountants/registrations#destroy
                               POST   /accountants(.:format)                                                                   accountants/registrations#create
                          root GET    /                                                                                        pages#home
                  registration GET    /registration(.:format)                                                                  pages#registration
```

Comment: Do you have a namespace called `accountants` ? if so try something like this `devise_for :accountants, controllers: { registrations: 'accountants/registrations' }`. This means you have a controller named `registration` under the scope `accountants`.

Comment: thanks for applying, I tried it, but same error. I put some raise in my newly created controllers, and I don't get to the raise. So I am not writing correctly the routes I guess, but I don't see the error

Comment: Try changing the url to `url: account_registration_path(resource_name))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change url for your sign up form like below , let me know if its not work

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: account_registration_url(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: error in the line of the super: ActionController::UnknownFormat in Accountants::RegistrationsController#create

Comment: i think the url is without the object, according to devise routes: POST   /accountants(.:format). Without the object, no error more, I am redirect to url accountants, where i see the sign up form, with the error, 6 characters minimum (and I put 6 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change URL for sign up form like below:

`<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: accountant_registration_path) do |f| %>`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't update the question, now updated. I used your strategy already, but rail render the form again, with the validation error, 6 characters minimum, and my password is 6 character long